# Implementation of max ulp deviation of single precision approximation

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm facing the same situation for several times now: I have an approximation of a given function (e.g. cosine) in single precision, and I want evaluate the maximum error of my approximation measured in ulp on a certain interval.

At the moment my approach is to firstly generate random single precision values (i know there are many discussions concerning random float generation on this site, which is why I don't want to discuss this in this question, but here is my code):

```
bool seedDone = false;
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine re;
float Floatrandom(float Min, float Max)
{   
    if (!seedDone)
    {
        re = std::default_random_engine(rd());
        seedDone = true;
    }
    
    //static std::default_random_engine e;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(Min, Max); 
    float x =  dis(re);
    if (x > Max || x < Min)
        std::cout << "Error: value out of bounds!" << std::endl;
    return x;
}
```

, calculating the trigonometric function with my approximation and a reference (for example cmath cosf) and comparing the results using:

```
int FloatCompareULP(float f1, float f2)
{
        assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int));
        int intDiff = abs(*(int*)&f1 - *(int*)&f2);
        return intDiff;
}
```

I imagine something like:

```
int calculateMaxULP(float(*approximation)(float), float(*reference)(float), float lowBound, float highBound)
```

But with random floats I can only give a propability that the maximum error is not larger than the biggest error i evaluated.

There is actually no possibility to iterate over all exisiting float, since my interval is way too big, and i would have to iterate over a few billions of values.

So I decided to "scan" the interval in small steps, and search more precisely around values with large errors. I am at the same time sure, that this method is not suitable, since an evaluation of the error distribution showed, that the latter is not continuous.
[[image: error distribution on 0,pi]

On the other hand, I already saw a lot of comments on different questions, that argue with max ulp error, so that it cannot be to difficult to implement a method.

edit: to specify my goal: i am not looking for a method that gives a mathematically correct proof, I just want to get a max ulp calculation to approximate the maximum error. I assume that my way is not the way to go.

If you need more information, do not hesitate to ask, I will edit this question to clarify misunderstandings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Re “There is actually no possibility to iterate over all exisiting float, since my interval is way too big, and i would have to iterate over a few billions of values”: This is possible and feasible. As I mentioned elsewhere, Apple’s `sinf`and `cosf` are tested over all possible inputs.

Comment: [Here](https://edp.org/work/Apple/sinfcosf.s) you can see some source code for Apple’s Intel `sinf` and `cosf` including comments that show how accuracy is demonstrated mathematically. This is for an implementation that uses double-precision, so not what you are implementing, but it illustrates that you need to be analyzing the floating-point operations mathematically. Whenever any operation is performed, we can express a bound on its error, and we can show the combinations of errors throughout the implementation result in a final bound on the result.

Comment: As I recall, on the Intel processors of over ten years ago, the initial exhaustive testing of `sinf` and `cosf` using GMP as a reference took some number of hours. But then there is a known-good implementation for which most results were correctly rounded. Then testing a modified implementation was done by first comparing each result to the known-good implementation (fast, around a few dozen CPU cycles per `cosf` call). Most of them passed. For those that did not, GMP (very slow) was called to see if the result was faithfully rounded (the criterion used for these implementations).

Comment: The result of that hybrid approach—a fast first filter with a known-good routine and a follow-up with GMP if necessary—completed the exhaustive testing of `cosf` in about four minutes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank your for your explanation. I assume there is no chance to implement the hybrid approach that you mentioned with manageable effort and knowledge. I will edit my question if thats the case.

Comment: @DexterS For single-argument `float` functions, if you don't have the time to code up a more sophisticated hybrid approach simply use an exhaustive test against a higher-precision reference. This should take under an hour on modern PC hardware, and if the CPU has multiple cores, the work can be split across cores so it only takes on the order of minutes. For two-argument `float` functions, for a simple approach, use random sampling, compare against a higher-precision reference, and let it run for a day or so.

Comment: If i decided to take the simple way using the exhaustive test... do you think my random float generwtion and m ulop calculation are appropriate from the perspective of a professional?

Comment: @njuffa I would appreciate if you could give me a short opinion about my approach, since I realized that you are very experienced at this topic

Comment: @njuffa Could you have a quick look at my ``int FloatCompareULP(float f1, float f2)`` method and tell if its correct according to your experience?